# How to determine that .background() requires Color specified, in order to then input a .colorName (as a text modifier)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Example code:

```
   Text("Hello")
      .background(Color.blue)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
```

I understand .background() requires me to specify **Color**.colorName inside the parentheses, while .foregroundColor() allows me to put .colorName name straight inside.

This led me to look at the docs.

.foregroundColor

```
func foregroundColor(_ color: Color?) -> some View
```

.background

```
func background<Background>(_ background: Background, alignment: Alignment = .center) -> some View where Background : View
```

So .foregroundColor takes in a Color struct. Easy enough.
While .background takes in a...Background? What's that? I couldn't find anything on Google.

My main question (for future reference using other functions), is that .background is capable of taking in a color by specifying Color.colorName.

***How could I have known that by looking at the docs?***

I don't want to "just know" that .background can take in a color by specifying Color.colorName.
What's more likely to happen is, I code it without first placing Color inside .background() like so:

```
   Text("Hello")
      .background(.blue)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
```

I get this error message I don't understand:

```
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'blue'
```

Check the docs.

Realise that .background takes in a...Background?

Given such a situation, how could I infer that I need to specify Color.colorName inside .background? Or that .background can even take a .colorName as input at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.background` takes a `View`
`Color.blue` works as a view, but you could just as easily use `.background(Circle())`

`func background<Background>(_ background: Background, alignment: Alignment = .center) -> some View where Background : View`

You asked how to tell that a Background is a generic View. If you look at the declaration you posted you'll see: `where Background : View`.
This is telling you that Background is generic but must conform to View.

while `.foregroundColor` specifically only takes a Color, so the type at the call site can be inferred by the compiler.

`func foregroundColor(_ color: Color?) -> some View`

---

At the call site, Xcode will show that it's expecting a View.

[image: Xcode completion]

---

In terms of functionality, think of `.background` as the opposite of `.overlay`, rather than as a colour modifier.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh. 
where Background : View. Would help if I could learn to read the docs properly... 

Thanks!

Comment: While I'm at it, in the definition where it says func background<Background>, why are <> being used around Background? I'm not sure what that syntax denotes. Does it mean, at a minimum, the function requires that parameter (Background) as input?

Comment: Great question! When a generic type is used in a swift function the generic type is denoted by angle brackets. Another example might be `func log<T>(words: T) where T: StringProtocol {}`. This matches the pattern seen when defining a struct that uses generics: `struct WordsToPrint<T: StringProtocol> {}` https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Comment: Hmmmm, I need a better understanding of genetics. Get the gist though, I’ll now not be “totally” clueless when I see those angle brackets. Cheers!